# Remove distinct records from sql query output

Tags: sql, sql-server

For my following query:

```
select sb.case, sb.Trace, sb.Amount, sp.edge, sp.UserId
from Budget sb join Sap sp 
     on sb.Trace= sp.Trace
where sb.Trace in 
(select Trace from Sap where sb.UserId in('R5','HB') 
order by sp.edge desc;
```

I am getting output as:

```
case        trace       amount  edge        userId
111243557   41432048    95.00   21631781    HB
111243557   40828826    95.00   21631781    R5
111243551   40828819    194.00  21631779    R5
111243545   40828600    71.00   21631773    R5
111243545   41431960    71.00   21631773    HB
```

How to remove the distinct row from the output.
Like here in output edge = 21631779 is distinct and need to be removed.
Can anyone please let me know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want output of edges that occur more than once, then you can use window functions:

```
with cte as (
      select sb.case, sb.Trace, sb.Amount, sp.edge, sp.UserId,
             count(*) over (partition by sp.edge) as cnt
      from Budget sb join
           Sap sp 
           on sb.Trace = sp.Trace
      where sb.Trace in (select Trace from Sap where sb.UserId in ('R5', 'HB'))
     )
select cte.*
from cte
where cnt > 1
order by edge desc;
```

Comment: I'm getting "The multi-part identifier "sp.edge" could not be bound." line 12

Answer (score 0):

Change the sp.edge for edge at the order by line

```
order by edge desc;
```