# finding difference between records in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

for query:

```
with cte as (
      select sb.case, sb.Trace, sb.Amount, sp.edge, sp.UserId,
             count(*) over (partition by sp.edge) as cnt
      from Budget sb join
           Sap sp 
           on sb.Trace = sp.Trace
      where sb.Trace in (select Trace from Sap where sb.UserId in ('R5', 'HB'))
     )
select cte.*
from cte
where cnt > 1
order by edge desc;
```

Following output is generated:

```
case        trace       amount  edge        userId                  cnt
110000061   40902752    357.00  21182786    HB                      2
110000061   40863651    161.00  21182786    R5                      2
```

Now, I need to display only those cases wrt to the amount difference.

For eg:
R5 user amount <= HB user amount-10 
i.e  `if (161<=[357-10])` then display the case 
Can anyone please let me know?

Comment: code taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663643/remove-distinct-records-from-sql-query-output

Comment: Can you explain further? (161<=[375-10]) Where did you get 10 and what should you do if the condition is true

Comment: 10 is constant value and if the condition is true we should display the corresponding case number. Like for the above output we should display 110000061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you already know you'll be dealing with 2 specific UserIds?

If yes, you could put those results you posted into a temp table and then join it to itself.....
So #TMP would contain..

```
case        trace       amount  edge        userId                  cnt
110000061   40902752    357.00  21182786    HB                      2
110000061   40863651    161.00  21182786    R5                      2
```

Then get what you want via this....

```
SELECT * FROM #TMP T1
INNER JOIN #TEMP T2 ON T2.case = T1.case
WHERE
ABS(ABS(T1.amount) - ABS(T2.AMOUNT)) >= 10   --A difference of 10 or more
```